# Prove that $f^{2016}(z)=z(z-1)\ldots(z-2015)$ for an analytic $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> Let $\Omega= \mathbb{C}\setminus \{x+iy:~x\in \mathbb{N},~y\geq 0\}$. Prove there there is an analytic function $f$ on $\Omega$, such that
>
> $$f^{2016}(z)=z(z-1)\ldots(z-2015).$$

I don't know where to start.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What does $f^{2016}$ mean here? Exponentiation? Function iteration?

Comment: It means exponentiation!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\Omega$ is simply connected and $z(z-1)\ldots(z-2015)$ has no zero in $\Omega$

Comment: Therefore $e^{g(z)}=z(z-1)\ldots(z-2015)$ for an analytic function $g$ and i can set $\displaystyle f(z)=\exp\Big\{\frac{1}{2016}g(z)\Big\}$?